# How to count set of letters from a list in prolog

Tags: arrays, list, prolog

I'm not familiar with  Prolog ,When I used the code below,I get the output as "false"

```
cvowel([],0).
vowel([a],Counter):-Counter is 1.
vowel([e],Counter):-Counter is 1.
vowel([i],Counter):-Counter is 1.
vowel([o],Counter):-Counter is 1.
vowel([u],Counter):-Counter is 1.
vowel([_];[],Counter):-Counter is 0.
cvowel([H|T],Counter1):-cvowel(T,Count),vowel(H,Counter),Count is Count
+Counter,Counter1 is Counter1+Count.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's see:

a) clauses of the same procedure should go together

```
cvowel([],0).
cvowel([H|T],Counter1):-
  cvowel(T,Count),
  vowel(H,Counter),
  Counter1 is Counter+Count.
  /* this is plain wrong: can be true only when Count,Counter and Counter1 are 0
  Count is Count+Counter,Counter1 is Counter1+Count
  */
```

b) this is *almost* a syntax error: Prolog syntax is not strict, thus your compiler could not complain about in a sensible way

```
vowel([_];[],Counter):-Counter is 0.
```

vowel/2 can be simplified - equivalently to your code - like this

```
vowel([a],1).
vowel([e],1).
...
vowel([_],0).
```

of course having *lists* as first argument of vowel/2 also seems wrong...

c) I think that simpler code is always better: consider a more declarative approach

```
vowel(a).
vowel(e).
...
% !! must NOT have vowel(_) !!

cvowel([H|T], Count) :-
 cvowel(T, Rest),
 (vowel(H) -> Count is Rest + 1 ; Count is Rest).
cvowel([], 0).
```

Comment: "->" what do you this symbol?@Capellic

Comment: @Ann which Prolog interpreter are you using? That should be documented in the manual. It's an implication (if-then) operator. `A -> B` will evaluate `B` if `A` succeeds (is true). If `A` fails, then `A -> B` fails. The construct `(A -> B ; C)` provides an if-then-else effect. If `A` succeeds, then `B` is evaluated. Otherwise, `C` is evaluated.

Comment: Thanks @mbratch. That's a well detailed explanation.